# Calling Codeigniter Method URI without reconstructing class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, uri

I'm trying to call a Codeigniter URI through a jQuery .load function without reconstructing the class instance.

The original URI segments are like so: `/culture/edit/190`.

This initial call builds a form with the inputs preloaded with the ID's info.
I store the initial row ID's for various tables involved in a protected class variable (called by `$this->editIds`), so that I can later compare the submitted form with the original ID's to see if they have changed.

Submitting the form calls a URI like: `/culture/do_edit`, which receives post data from the potentially altered form, and then prepares insert statements.

I need to check the IDs to make sure that (if they are changed) the user is not trying to duplicate ID's. If the ID is changed to a unique value (if at all), the record has it's ID changed without complaint; if it has not changed at all, then it can continue with ease.

The problem (I think) is that the class is re-constructed, and I lose the original data in the variable set earlier, because `do_edit` see's the variable as empty (initial constructor state).

I've tried altering how the ajax method is called:

```
$('#message').load('/culture/do_edit', data);
```

which results in the URI: `/culture/do_edit`, and reconstructs the class.

or

```
$('#message').load('do_edit', data);
```

which results in the URI `/culture/edit/do_edit`, which actually passes the method edit the parameter `do_edit`.

I want to preserve the class instance so the original ID's are available for comparison.

I could pass the original ID's in hidden inputs with the post, but I'd rather not add extra inputs if I can avoid it. Is there a way to call a method without crawling through the whole URI and reconstructing?

Or should I go about the comparison a different way?

Comment: use jQuery $.get instead of load, add onsuccess: function () { $formValues = $('#message > form').serialize(); } this would store the form values in a variable you can access later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try storing the serialized object in a session and unserialize it when you need it again.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

PHP doesn't keep the instance available for you after each http request.

I recommend you use hidden fields, make things easier. Storing these serialized objects in session may be hard for you to troubleshoot your app.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll go with a couple hidden inputs to hold the ID's, as it seems the simplest approach with easy expandability if needed.